# How to Redirect to Another Application in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I've researched it all over StackOverflow and Google but only get results about C# and irrelevant topics, so now I have to ask. I want after 20 seconds of the application being open to close itself and open another application that is in the same folder. After I have debugged, I copy the application to the folder on my Desktop that I will eventually ZIP up. But I want the app to open another application in the folder. Say for instance  `ApplicationA.exe` Opens and after 20 seconds it closes and `ApplicationB.exe` opens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CreateProcess()` winapi function which acts like `fork()`+`exec()` and then `exit()` the `ApplicationA`. Also you can use `Sleep(miliseconds)` for the delay.

Here is the information about `CreateProcess()`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can open it with system("ApplicationB.exe");  and then exit.  This will start ApplicationB.exe and exit ApplicationA.exe.

Check out: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/18057-run-external-executable/

Answer (score 0):

I believe C++ is not really the best way to go for system calls like the ones you need to do here. Maybe shell scripting would be a better option.

Anyway, the easiest way is probably writing a third program that opens ApplicationA.exe, closes it and starts ApplicaionB.exe.

I believe in C++ you'd have to use `system`, which you find in `<cstdlib>`. Yes, it is a C feature, not a C++ one, and its use is not encouraged, to put it mildly.

Comment: Well, I was just told by my Uncle, who actually makes computers and owns his own computer company and has developed numerous windows applications, to do C++

Comment: In C++ you'd have to use a C library (namely cstdlib) to do system calls, or otherwise use some winapi like the one suggested by Johnny. In a shell script it takes 4 lines to accomplish the same thing. As an example, in bash the script would be:
`A.exe&`;
`sleep 20`;
`pkill A.exe`;
`B.exe`;

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the ShellExecute function. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx